# Django. Запуск сервера. Exception in thread django-main-thread.Ошибки юникодов

Tags: django

Собственно запускаю сервер и появляются ошибки в консоли.
Я мигрировал manage.py. И запускал runserver 127.0.0.1:8000. Я заходил на похожие запросы, не помогла миграция.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
(c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corp.), 2009. Все права защищены.

C:\Users\Таирлан>D:

D:\>cd Django

D:\Django>cd myfirst

D:\Django\myfirst>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.

D:\Django\myfirst>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
August 15, 2020 - 14:29:58
Django version 3.1, using settings 'myfirst.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Таирлан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading
.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Таирлан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading
.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Таирлан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-pack
ages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Таирлан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-pack
ages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 139, in inner_run
    run(self.addr, int(self.port), handler,
  File "C:\Users\Таирлан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-pack
ages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 206, in run
    httpd = httpd_cls(server_address, WSGIRequestHandler, ipv6=ipv6)
  File "C:\Users\Таирлан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-pack
ages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 67, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Таирлан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socketser
ver.py", line 452, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Users\Таирлан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\s
imple_server.py", line 50, in server_bind
    HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "C:\Users\Таирлан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\serv
er.py", line 140, in server_bind
    self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
  File "C:\Users\Таирлан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socket.py
", line 756, in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd2 in position 0: invalid
continuation byte
```

Comment: Покажите файлы моделей(models.py)

Comment: Пустая она. лишь одна строка

Comment: from django.db import models